# Display an SAP portlet in SharePoint 2013 page

Tags: 2013, iframe

I am trying to display the SAP workitem portlet in a SharePoint 2013 page. I tried using `iframe` or `object` tag but it just keep going into infinite loop and refreshing.

In some FireFox browser version, it displays the mesage :

> A possible cross frame scripting attack has been detected and please refer to SAP note to 1651004.

We have verified the notes and ensure the settings are done but we are still having the infinite loop in the `iframe` area (to SAP workitem portlet) in SharePoint 2013 page.

Can someone advise how I can display the SAP workitems portlet in SharePoint page?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the page and insert a [Page Viewer Webpart](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Display-a-Web-page-on-a-SharePoint-page-by-adding-the-Page-Viewer-Web-Part-7f61feec-9b3d-4805-a960-07636ba59527).

Now edit the webpart properties and set `Link` property to the target SAP page.

Save and refresh the page.

*Note - If you still have issues, then it is not related to SharePoint*

Comment: Hi. I have tried using Page Viewer webpart but I am still having that problem.